# Why I keep getting undefined? I'm using Stipe with Next.JS

Tags: javascript, next.js, stripe-payments, next.js13

I have my .env.local as per below:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = pk_test_apikeycontinues
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = sk_test_apikeycontinues
```

and this is my ./app/utils/stripe.js file:

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';

export const stripe = Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
```

Now this is my code on my homepage:

```
'use client'

import { stripe } from "./utils/stripe";

export default function Home({ products }) {
  console.log(products);
  
  return (
    <div>
      home
    </div>
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const inventory = await stripe.products.list({
    limit: 5,
  });
  
  return {
    props: {
      products: inventory,
    },
  };
}
```

I have already an existing inventory in the test preview, but I keep getting "undefined" on my console log.

I tried encoding the API key inside the homepage and skip the other 2 files just to test it out, but I still keep getting undefined.

```
'use client'

import Stripe from 'stripe';

export const stripe = Stripe("sk_test_apikeycontinues");

export default function Home({ products }) {
  console.log(products);
  
  return (
    <div>
      home
    </div>
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const inventory = await stripe.products.list({
    limit: 5,
  });
  
  return {
    props: {
      products: inventory,
    },
  };
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Instead of focusing on the API key, why not do some simple debugging? Wrap your `stripe.products.list()` in a `try..catch` and log any errors. It seems very unlikely that the Stripe SDK would resolve with an `undefined` value

Answer (score 0):

for your `'use client'` statement I can guess that you are using Next 13.

Next 13 replace some methods and `getStaticProps` is one of them.
You can use fetch function to get the data.

check this [migration guide](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#static-site-generation-getstaticprops)

But you will have another problem since your component is a client component and next is still working in that part.

> Wrapping fetch in use is currently not recommended in Client Components and may trigger multiple re-renders. For now, if you need to fetch data in a Client Component, we recommend using a third-party library such as SWR or React Query.
> Please check this part [use in client components](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching#use-in-client-components).

To solve this problem I did a function to avoid re-renders

```
const fetchMap = new Map<string, Promise<any>>();
function queryClient<QueryResult>(
  name: string,
  query: () => Promise<QueryResult>
): Promise<QueryResult> {
  if (!fetchMap.has(name)) {
    fetchMap.set(name, query());
  }
  return fetchMap.get(name)!;
}
```

And then inside your component

```
  const { product } = use(
    queryClient(
      "putANameToYourFunctionHere",
      () =>
        fetch("http://yourURL/product", {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify({ slug }),
        }).then((res) => res.json()) as Promise<{ product: IProduct }>
    )
  );
```

I get this function from a video on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwQs4wXr9Bg&t=756s&ab_channel=JackHerrington)

Hope be helpfull for you :)

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciate the answer. Let me try if I can make it work.

Comment: No problem!, let me know if works or if is anything else that I can help you :)